# How to get postgresSQL to work on a windows 7 computer with django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, installation

I'm currently reading the [django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter02/) and their instructions aren't working for me. People are talking about editing their paths and needing full paths in the comments and I really just have no idea what they are talking about to be honest. I got django to install correctly but I can't for the life of me figure this out. Any suggestions or explanations of peoples comment would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, your question does not make much sense. You say: "I got django to install correctly but I can't for the life of me figure this out." What can't you figure out? Please be more specific. Did you manage to install the PostgreSQL database? Did you manage to install `psycopg` package?

Comment: if you got to the django book it explain how to make a new database with command that says  "django-admin.py startproject mysite" and when I type that into the command prompt it come back with django-admin.py is not a recognized internal or external command. and then the comments are riddled with people editting their path and stuff.

I can't figure out how to make a new database via their directions. or in essence how to make a new database in django? I'm not exactly sure.

also yes I installed the pscycog package.

Comment: OK, that's two, somewhat specific questions, not bad. For the 1st one, regarding the paths, make sure you read through and understand this http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-run-a-python-program-under-windows. You cannot skip and save that one. For the 2nd: have you also installed the PostgreSQL? http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/

Comment: @bpgergo pretty much gave you all the direction you need with his answer, but just to correct your terminology a bit: django-admin.py will help you start a new django project, not create a database. Once you have a project, you can configure its settings.py file and from there you can use `./manage.py syncdb` to actually create your database. I just didn't want you to become confused when you didn't actually create a db from the `startproject` command

Comment: @bpgergo yes I have the postgresql installed. and alright I'm reading that over as we speak. thankyou both for your help. sorry about the bad formatting of the question. I thought the title was a good enough summary but obviously not. I'll try to make my questions more descroptive in the furute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before you do anything, make sure that you have `C:\Python27\Scripts` added to your `PATH`, this is where most packages install their scripts (such as django-admin.py).

*Replace `C:\Python27` with wherever Python is installed in your system*

Once you have done that, *open a new command prompt* so the system will read the `PATH`.

`C:\>python django-admin.py startproject myproject`

Should work without any problems.

Next, install postgresql. The easiest way is to use the [one click installer](http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/).

Finally, download the [pyscopg library](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg) for Windows. Make sure you pick the one that corresponds with your version of Python.

Now you can continue by creating a database in postgresql. Use the pgadmin tool (called `pgadmin III`).

1. Expand the `Servers` tree under `Server Groups` on the left pane.
2. Double click on the server listed (should be `PostgreSQL 9.0 (localhost:5432)`). This connects you to the server. You need to use the password you set up in the installer.
3. Right click on `Login Roles`, and select `New Role..`
4. Fill in the `Role name` (this is the user's login name)
5. Enter two passwords.
6. Click OK.
7. Right click on `Databases`, and select `New Database..`
8. Give it a name
9. In the `Owner` field, enter the name you entered in `Role name` in step 4.
10. Click OK

From here on, you can follow the instructions in the tutorial.

Comment: I get an error that says their is no such file in the directory however when i put the path all the way into where django-admin.py is located it works. any suggestions?

Comment: nvm. I followed you instructions and figured out how to get it to work. I'm not sure if I did it all correctly but I did it good enough to wok lol. thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the detail. I found this answer useful.

Comment: @jimmyjimmy How? I tried the same and I failed. It says there's no database

Comment: Note that the EnterpriseDB distribution of PostgreSQL for Windows includes a bundled copy of [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/windows.php).